# In Ansible, run only one item in a loop based on a variable

Tags: ansible

In my Ansible playbook I set up a number of websites on one server. Each website has some configuration set in an `apps` variable:

```yaml
apps:
  - name: 'app1'
    git_repo: 'https://github.com/philgyford/app1.git'
  - name: 'app2'
    git_repo: 'https://github.com/philgyford/app2.git'
```

Then certain tasks are run in a loop for every app/site:

```yaml
- name: Set up git repos for apps
  git:
    repo: '{{ item.git_repo }}'
    version: 'master'
    dest: "/webapps/{{ item.name }}"
    accept_hostkey: yes
  with_items: apps
```

That's all fine. But ideally I'd like to be able to run the playbook and only run these tasks for a specific app.

One way would be to pass in `--extra-vars "app=app1"` on the command line. In the playbook I'd set a default value for `app` of `false`. And then on every app-related task add:

```yaml
  when: item.name == app or app == false
```

This should work, but it seems laborious and error-prone to have to add that to every single task. Is there a more elegant way that avoids so much repetition?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can filter lists with the [`selectattr` filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#selectattr) like so:

```
apps | selectattr('name', 'match', app)
```

Beside your `apps` definition you could have a filtered list, which defaults to the full list:

```
vars:
  apps:
    - name: 'app1'
      git_repo: 'https://github.com/philgyford/app1.git'
    - name: 'app2'
      git_repo: 'https://github.com/philgyford/app2.git'

  active_apps: "{{ apps if app is not defined else apps | selectattr('name', 'match', app) | list }}"
```

Then in your loop you would loop over `active_apps` instead and no further condition is required.

```
- name: Set up git repos for apps
  git:
    repo: '{{ item.git_repo }}'
    version: 'master'
    dest: "/webapps/{{ item.name }}"
    accept_hostkey: yes
  with_items: active_apps
```

The `match` filter used in `selectattr` actually takes a regular expression. So you could provide very detailed expressions which apps to process.

```
--extra-vars "app=app1"
--extra-vars "app=app[12]"
--extra-vars "app=app.*"
--extra-vars "app=app1|app2"
...
```

But be careful with this. `--extra-vars "app=app1"` would also match `app10` etc.

Comment: That sounds like just what I need, thanks! I wondered if there was something like this, but couldn't quite work it out. I won't have a chance to try it out for a couple of days, but will mark this correct when it works.

Comment: Really useful example - just what I was looking for.

To get around the `--extra-vars "app=app1"` also matching `app10` you can use the `equalto` filter e.g. `selectattr('name', 'equalto', app)` (although I had to upgrade Jinja2)